# How to disable some specific USB ports

Tags: windows-xp, usb

I have a Windows XP machine with Gigabyte EP31-DS3l Mobo. There are two ports on front panel and 4 on back. For some reason I want to disable those two front ones. That is I want to have just the backs worked and not the fronts.
Is there any way to do this please?

Comment: You can also disable this ports through a group policy

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to simply disconnect the cable linking the front ports to the USB header on the motherboard. There *may* be a software option but this will do what you want.

Comment: The USB header on the board will be marked quite clearly, the ports on my Gigabyte X58 board certainly are. If in doubt refer to the motherboard manual, download it from Gigabyte if you don't know where yours is.

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is grab two `USBs` plug one in the front and the second in the back panel then open the `Device Manager` from the `System Properties` window.

There is a section called `Universal Serial Bus Controller` expend the tree to view all the devices from here you have `Generic USB Hub` devices the number of these devices depends on the number of the `USB` panels you have in your system, select any one and disable it. and check which `USB` hub is not working.

Does this until you get the desired result.